# How to stop layout from changing size when activity goes in full screen mode?

Tags: android

I have a activity that shows image slider using `ViewPAger`. By default activity is in full screen mode. When I click on `ImageView` full screen mode will be disabled if enabled and enable if it is disabled. I am using below code to achieve that.

Code to enable full screen mode

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

and code to disable full screen mode

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

It is working fine but the problem is my layout size gets changed, How to fix it? I want same like google photos.

[full screen mode enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH3g9.png)

[full screen mode disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAdjK.png)

I want to show image same as shown in second image while activity is in full screen mode.

Here is my main activity layout file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/navigationBarColor">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/back_lay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="#26808080"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#26808080"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_share" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#26808080"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my adapter item layout file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/relative_container"
android:background="@color/navigationBarColor">


    <com.example.hp.mygallery.CommonFiles.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/back_lay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#26808080"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#26808080"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_share" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#26808080"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/delete"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/play_lay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you mention any screen shot what is happening on screen?

Comment: can you show show your xml file

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Please check my code.

Comment: code is correct you have use style it with themes

Comment: how to use style to achieve what i want?

Comment: getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
works for me.Thanks for the reply @AbhinavGupta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable full screen mode use,

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

To disable full screen mode use.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
```